# How to show page_title instead of post_title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I had the idea to create a div with the class 90. where the `<?php the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); ?>` of the page is shown in a 90° angle.

Works great. Just some tweaking to get the layout working correctly.

I added in the reading settings the option that A static page is selected for my posts.
Now I want that the page titel is shown in the DIV 90 and not the post title. But apparently the `<?php the_title ?>` is for both of them.

Is there a way to determine what title you want selected? So in this case load/echo the page title and dismiss the post title.

Hope I explained it right.

Comment: RTFM? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title  it only ever gives you the post title. perhaps you want [wp_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) instead?

Comment: Do we ever RTFM :p.

Complete missed the wp_title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a search in the WordPress codex, has a lot of useful information there..

https://codex.wordpress.org/

This is what I believe you are after:

```
<h3><?php wp_title(); ?></h3>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/

Comment: Indeed it was! Can't believe I didn't see it. Maybe coding for 10h straigt wasn't a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I helped, would you be a kind gent and up vote and mark as the correct answer? Thanks bud

Comment: Sure, bud! 
Cui honorem, honorem deberi ;)